# UK Fiancé Visa Complication

Tags: uk-visa

My fiancé and I are getting ready to apply for a U.K. Fiancé visa but there is a problem.

We meet the financial requirements and accommodation requirements but how we met and his circumstances are tricky.

We met online 2 years ago while he was still with his ex girlfriend. We talked everyday for a year before becoming romantically involved. However he only officially broke up with his ex girlfriend one month ago so he could bring me over and we could get married. Their relationship was emotionally and physically over before he met me but they never officially broke it off for their 2 kids.

They were renting the same flat together and were still living together up until a month ago when he got enough money together to comfortably leave. The 2 kids who live with her.

I visited him in October and November 2015 and January and March 2016. He visited me in June 2016.

Even though their relationship was unofficially over for a long time it only became official a month ago so he technically cheated on her with me. They were never married.

How do we explain this to the officer who will be reviewing our case? Will the officer be more inclined to refuse if he did technically cheat on her with me? We've been in a genuine relationship for over a year and only want to be able to live and be together.

Comment: I think all they care about is that your relationship is genuine and thatyou canlegally marry. I don't think a part record of infidelity, whether real or imagined, or purely "technical," is relevant.

Comment: Thank you- How would we explain it to the officer though?

Comment: Your main problem may be to prove that you and your fiance have a genuine relationship and that any prior relationships are permanently broken down. See [Apply to join family living permanently in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/eligibility). There does not seem to be any requirement to have been faithful in prior relationships.

Comment: I think they're going to care more about monetary evidence of the genuine nature of your relationship, e.g. plane tickets for visits and so on. If they do ask, tell them - don't lie. But I don't think that it will be an issue.